# Unable to Uninstall WiX Managed Bootstrapper application from another Managed Bootstrapper Application

Tags: c#, mvvm, wix, bootstrapper, wix3.10

I have my own Managed Bootstrapper Application developed using WiX Toolset and written in c# using MVVM pattern. As this is a Managed Bootstrapper Application, i have a custom UI as well. My Bundle.wxs Code is as follows

```
<Bundle Name="NestleMESSetup"
          Version="!(bind.packageVersion.NestleCustomLayerSetupPackage)"
          Manufacturer="CT Infotech"
              UpgradeCode="CCBB8D5B-8171-47FB-AD53-25C6E866C34E"
              Copyright="Copyright© 2017 CT Infotech ALL RIGHTS RESERVED"
              SplashScreenSourceFile="Resources\Splash.bmp"
              IconSourceFile="Resources\menu.ico">

        <Variable Name="KambanVersion" Type="version" Value="!(bind.packageVersion.KambanFASSetup)"/>

        <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
          <PayloadGroupRef Id="InstallerPayload"/>
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <util:RegistrySearchRef Id='SearchForKamban' />

        <Chain>
          <PackageGroupRef Id="InstallerPackages"/>
        </Chain>

        <Variable Name="DbName" bal:Overridable="yes" />
        <Variable Name="SqlInstance" bal:Overridable="yes" />
        <Variable Name="InstallPath" bal:Overridable="yes" />
        <Variable Name="Roles" bal:Overridable="yes" />
        <Variable Name="Modules" bal:Overridable="yes" />
        <Variable Name="CustomInstall" bal:Overridable="yes"/>

        <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="Netfx4Full" />
        <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="NetfxLicense.rtf" />

      </Bundle>

      <Fragment>
        <PayloadGroup Id="InstallerPayload">
          <Payload SourceFile="..\Nestle.MES.Bootstrapper.UI\BootstrapperCore.config"/>
          <Payload SourceFile="..\Nestle.MES.Bootstrapper.UI\bin\$(var.Configuration)\Nestle.MES.Bootstrapper.UI.dll"/>
          <Payload SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"/>
        </PayloadGroup>
      </Fragment>

      <Fragment>
        <PackageGroup Id="InstallerPackages">
          <RollbackBoundary Id="StartingPoint" Vital="yes" />
          <ExePackage Id="KambanFASSetup" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" Vital="yes" Permanent="no" Name="KambanCoreSetup"
                      SourceFile="..\..\Kamban.FAS.Setup_Source\$(var.Configuration)\KambanFASSetup.exe" >
            <CommandLine InstallArgument="[SqlInstance]" Condition="1" />
            <CommandLine InstallArgument="[DbName]" Condition="1"/>
            <CommandLine InstallArgument="[InstallPath]" Condition="1"/>
            <CommandLine InstallArgument="[Roles]" Condition="1"/>
            <CommandLine InstallArgument="[Modules]" Condition="1" />
            <CommandLine InstallArgument="[CustomInstall]" Condition="1"/>
          </ExePackage>

          <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\..\build_folder\$(var.Configuration)\Nestle.MES.CustomLayer\Nestle.MES.CustomLayerSetup.msi"
                      Id="NestleCustomLayerSetupPackage" Cache="yes" Visible="no" Compressed="yes" EnableFeatureSelection="yes" Vital="yes">
            <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]"  />
            <MsiProperty Name="VERSION" Value="[VERSION]"/>
            <MsiProperty Name="ADDLOCAL" Value="[NestleFeatures]" />
          </MsiPackage>
        </PackageGroup>
      </Fragment>

      <Fragment>
        <util:RegistrySearch
          Id='SearchForKamban'
          Variable="KambanInstalled"
          Result="exists"
          Root="HKLM"
          Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\KambanFAS" />
        <bal:Condition Message="Product already Exists">
          KambanInstalled
        </bal:Condition>
      </Fragment>
```

In the above code, you can see that I have an MsiPackage and an ExePackage in my Bundle chain. The ExePackage with **Id="KambanFASSetup"** is also a Managed Bootstrapper Application with its very own custom UI. Once I install this Parent bundle exe, i get two entries in my Programs and Features. I believe this is because i have two managed bootstrapper exe. So now while uninstalling the **NestleMESSetup** only my MsiPackage is getting uninstaled and my ExePackage doesnt.  But my requirement is as follows

- The ExePackage should also be uninstalled if I uninstall the Parent Exe.
- The Uninstallation of the Child ExePackage must happen silently. i.e
  It's UI should **NOT** be shown prompting the user to click the Uninstall
  button again.

Please let me know if more info is needed.Any help on this would be much appreciated.

**Edit1:**
Here is the Uninstall logs in %temp% folder

```
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i001: Burn v3.10.2.2516, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{a21ebf3e-08b2-4b64-b5bf-38dccfea21a2}\Nestle.MES.Setup.exe
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i000: Initializing version variable 'KambanVersion' to value '1.0.647.0'
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i009: Command Line: '/uninstall'
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\RAJASA~1.000\AppData\Local\Temp\NestleMESSetup_20170519192711.log'
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'CT Infotech'
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i000: Loading managed bootstrapper application.
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i000: Creating BA thread to run asynchronously.
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i000: Setting numeric variable 'KambanInstalled' to value 1
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i101: Detected package: KambanFASSetup, state: Absent, cached: None
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i101: Detected package: NestleCustomLayerSetupPackage, state: Present, cached: Complete
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i104: Detected package: NestleCustomLayerSetupPackage, feature: AppFeatures, state: Local
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i104: Detected package: NestleCustomLayerSetupPackage, feature: WebFeatures, state: Local
[2658:3330][2017-05-19T19:27:11]i104: Detected package: NestleCustomLayerSetupPackage, feature: DbFeatures, state: Local
```

**Edit2:**
With the Detect Condition added to my Bundle chain Exe package I am not able to Uninstall the Parent exe as well. The WiX logs are as follows

```
[1450:1BBC][2017-05-20T07:33:59]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{c8fb8ef8-905f-4bd9-8675-91f62d83e5c8}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1644:0F04][2017-05-20T07:33:59]w341: Prompt for source of container: WixAttachedContainer, path: E:\TFS_Nestle\Nestle\build_folder\Debug\Nestle.MES.Setup\Nestle.MES.Setup.exe
[1644:0F04][2017-05-20T07:33:59]e054: Failed to resolve source for file: E:\TFS_Nestle\Nestle\build_folder\Debug\Nestle.MES.Setup\Nestle.MES.Setup.exe, error: 0x80070002.
[1644:0F04][2017-05-20T07:33:59]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed while prompting for source (original path 'E:\TFS_Nestle\Nestle\build_folder\Debug\Nestle.MES.Setup\Nestle.MES.Setup.exe').    [1644:0F04][2017-05-20T07:33:59]e311: Failed to acquire container: WixAttachedContainer to working path: C:\Users\RAJASA~1.000\AppData\Local\Temp\{B5BE6652-F453-40B5-A2BF-6313B191EA7F}\9FD1B9E707102B3EB2E75EA87962C5C839E9588A, error: 0x80070002.
[1644:1B24][2017-05-20T07:33:59]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[1450:1BBC][2017-05-20T07:33:59]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{c8fb8ef8-905f-4bd9-8675-91f62d83e5c8}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[1450:1BBC][2017-05-20T07:33:59]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{c8fb8ef8-905f-4bd9-8675-91f62d83e5c8}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1644:1B24][2017-05-20T07:33:59]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070002, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[1644:1B24][2017-05-20T07:33:59]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
```

Comment: The absolute first thing you have to do is run the uninstall with verbose logging on.  I know how to do that with MSI installers, I don't know how to do that with bootstrapped installers.  I'm sure that information is available on the innertubes somewhere, if you search for it.  Get that log and [edit] it into your question.

Comment: @Will I examined the Uninstall logs and found out that my ExePackage is not getting detected. Its state is Absent. Attached my Logs under **Edit1**

Comment: @raja_89 Because you do not have DetectCondition

Answer (score 3):

Your ExePackage is missing the UninstallCommand attribute so burn does not know how to properly uninstall it.  It should be something like

```
UninstallCommand="/uninstall /quiet"
```

and may be some additions if needed.

And for burn to be able to detect the ExePackage, it should define the attribute DetectCondition.  Something like

```
DetectCondition="KambanInstalled"
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. Now that I have added a Detect Condition, my Exe package gets detected. But now with the Detect Condition added,  I am not able to Uninstall the Parent Bundle as well. The WiX logs are attached in **Edit2**